# How to apply pixellate effect over video for few second using gpuimage in iOS?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, gpuimage, video-editing, video-effects

I am looking for ways to apply visual effect like pixellate,ghost,twirl,X-ray etc. over currently playing video for few seconds not over whole video duration using GPUImage library.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the filter values while running a video processing. So you can use NSTimer to schedule the effect changes.